# What is this iron pipe in my attic?

Tags: insulation, attic

In a Canadian 1950s home. In a knee wall or cubby hole. Not attached directly to the roof, but not easily moveable due to the way the pipe is constructed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Phil   I would make a new question about the insulation.  Roof decks should have ventilation.  That attic does not look like living space so the insulation will probably be better on the floor/between the joists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an iron vent pipe. See the whole thing disassembled here: [Vent Pipe Replacement In Attic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/202216/vent-pipe-replacement-in-attic)

While you are at it, remove the craft paper from the insulation. It's not supposed to be left exposed.

Comment: thanks! I was wondering about that paper stuff. thought it was some kind of vapour barrier or something.

Comment: @Phil Yes, it is indeed a vapor barrier. But because it is flammable, it must be covered with sheetrock and not left exposed.

Comment: wow! thanks. good to know